# Не подключается шрифт ChunkFiveEx

Tags: шрифты

```
@font-face {font-family:"ChunkFiveEx";
    src:url("../fonts/Chunkfive_Ex.eot?") format("eot"),
        url("../fonts/Chunkfive_Ex.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/Chunkfive_Ex.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("../fonts/Chunkfive_Ex.svg#ChunkFiveEx") format("svg");
        font-weight:normal;
        font-style:normal;
}
```

Это готовый фонт, но кирилица неработает.
http://www.fonts2u.com/chunkfiveex.font скачивал с этого сайта.
Ладно, тогда сам делаю с этого сайта font скачиваю и пытаюсь преобразовать вот этим сервисом http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator, но он почему то выдает ошибку. Подскажите, в чем причина ошибки на этом сайте? Ошибка вида "IO Error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключился! С 50 попытки! Наверное какие-то поломки на сайте были. Все спасибо.Все работает. Сделал через  http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator. только в ИЕ7 не работает